# command line tool it always crashes "dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: ____chkstk_darwin"

Tags: node.js, macos

This happens to any command line tool I build. after install node latest version

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: ____chkstk_darwin
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/node (which was built for Mac OS X 10.15)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: ____chkstk_darwin
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/node (which was built for Mac OS X 10.15)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

Abort trap: 6
```

Do you have any recommend? I really dont know what's happening here

Answer (score 23, accepted):

the problem was with the node version. It was not suitable for my version of Mac, which is macOS 10.13.
I deleted node 18 and installed node 16
after that it worked

Comment: Also macOS 10 reached end of life support. Only Sharp version `0.31.1` or lower will work with macOS 10, latest ones will crash, as per Sharp owner: https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/3438#issuecomment-1342722874

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the [comment by KeitelDOG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74405288/command-line-tool-it-always-crashes-dyld-lazy-symbol-binding-failed-symbol-no#comment132692299_74406357):

If you're running OSX 10 Catalina, you'll need to use a specific version 0.31.1 of the `sharp` npm package, because it is the latest version of sharp that still works on OSX 10. Newer versions of sharp only work on OSX 11 and higher due to an newer xcode dependency.

```
npm uninstall sharp and
npm install sharp@0.31.1
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm using macOS High Sierra and was facing this having installed node v18.
When I reinstalled the node v16.20, the issue got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I got stack in the same problem then i install version 16.17.1 and it worked fine